# bash if specific character exists

Tags: bash

I am creating a script to automate partitioning of a harddrive.

Now I am having trouble with the following stuff:

I need to check if a "." exists in a text file. (so just the dot).
What is the best way to accomplish this?.

Example:

```
hdhelft=`cat /sometextfile`
if grep "." $hdhelft    
then    
hdhelf2=something    
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to read the file into a variable unless that's what you really want. It's not entirely clear from your code what you want, but here's my interpretation. Use the `-F` flag to `grep` to get it to interpret the . as a literal, and the `-q` so it doesn't give any output (just yes or no). Also, if you really want `$hdhelft` to contain the contents of the file, use `$(<filename)` to get that.

```
hdhelft=$(</sometextfile)
if grep -qF '.' /sometextfile; then
    hdhelf2=something
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `.` character as grep interprets that as "any character". So use:

```
grep '\.' yourfile
```